# What are valid attributes to input as a parameter for element.contains()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Question in short: What can I put as a the node parameter to `element.contains(node)`?

My understanding is that a node can be an element, attribute node, text, or something else. So why is it if I do `element.contains(datetime)` I receive an error? Other examples I have seen include `element.contains(span)` but I can't find an example of finding an attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer
The official syntax is

> node.contains(node)

`node` should be a `node`, not a `string`, or `datetime`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_contains.asp

> My understanding is that a node can be an element, attribute node, text, or something else.

No, thats wrong. An element/node is actually just a `<TAG>` - Element

Comment: So I can't check if a node contains a certain attribute without looping over children elements?

Comment: Attributes are something different `<span id="text">Text</span>` id is an attribute in that case

Comment: @mruben09 checkout the DOM-API for attributes : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_attributes.asp

Comment: Ah, okay. I had a bad misunderstanding of what a node was. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Last line is not true.. There are indeed text nodes, comment nodes etc